# Integral estimate for positive part

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expectation

I'm somewhat stuck on understanding, what seems to be a kind of elementary estimate. Let

1. $X\geq 0$ with $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$.
2. $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R} $ and $f(x)\geq-c>-1$.
3. Let $A$ be some arbitrary event from the probability space.

How can I show that

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)\right)^+\mathbf1_A\right]\leq c+\mathbb{E}\left[f(X)\right]$$

**EDIT**: $(\cdot)^+$ is defined as $\max{(\cdot,0)}$.

Comment: What is $A$ here?

Comment: What is $f(X)^+$ ? is it $f(X)\vee 0$ ?

Comment: @Surb precisely. Thanks for the questions, I'll clarify in the opening post.

Comment: @ClementC. an arbitrary event from the probability space, thanks for the question, I'll clarify.

Comment: @joedoe8585: Are you sure that $(\cdot )^+$ is not $\max(\cdot ,0)$ ?(and not the $\min$).

Comment: @Surb; You're right of course, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f(X) = f(X)^+ - f(X)^-$. Then, observe that the bound $f \geq -c$ implies $f(X)^- \leq c$ a.s., so that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)^+ - f(X)^-]
= \mathbb{E}[f(X)^+] - \mathbb{E}[f(X)^-]
\geq \mathbb{E}[f(X)^+] - c
$$
and reorganizing the terms give what you want: $\mathbb{E}[f(X)^+] \leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)] + c$.

*Note that this does not require the assumption $X \geq 0$ (except for $f(X)$ to be defined, if you really want the domain of $f$ to be $\mathbb{R}_+$) nor $\mathbb{E} X =1$.*

Now, you can generalize to your specific expression by observing that $f(X)^+\mathbf{1}_A \leq f(X)^+$, since $f(X)^+ \geq 0$ a.s.: so that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)^+\mathbf{1}_A] \leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)^+] \leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)] + c.$$